# Filter array based on dynamic objects and values in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, array-filter

I have an array which contains a list of different objects and I want to be able to re-use the same function to filter different objects and values within the same array.

My array

```
cocktailList = [
  Object {
    "abv": "24",
    "alcoholic": "true",
    "strength": "medium",
    "type": Object {
      "key": 3,
      "label": "Medium",
      "value": "medium",
    ...,
    ...,
    },
  },
  Object {
    ...
  },
]
```

and I'm calling a function to filter the array passing 2 parameters:

- the field I want to filter on
- the value it should filter out

This is my function and the caller

```
const drinkTypeHandler = (field, value) => {       
    const selectedType = cocktailList.filter((cocktail) => cocktail.field === value);
    console.log(selectedType); 
}

onPress={() => drinkTypeHandler(item.field, item.value)}
```

The function is picking up the "value" param fine but it is not using the "field" param I'm passing.
I tried to pass it as dynamic param as follows but still no success

```
cocktailList.filter((cocktail) => `cocktail.${field} === ${value}`)
```

If I hardcode the field value it works

```
i.e.
cocktailList.filter((cocktail) => cocktail.type.value === value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a dynamic field name, you have to use square brackets. So you would use:

`cocktailList.filter((cocktail) => cocktail[field] === value)`

The issue you are going to run into is the nested key / value pairs under `type` as you can't use something like `type.value` with that notation.

Comment: thank @veddermatic - Is there any solution to access the nested key/value pairs?

Comment: Not a simple one-liner. You will have to see if the function was called with `"type"` as the `field` param and then return the `value` property there, or take in a second param for the nested lookup: `cocktail[field][subfield]`

Comment: That's excellent, I managed to find a solution easily following your explanation. I'm splitting the parameter as [field] [subfield] and adding a check. Based on the value of the flag I can use cocktail[field] or cocktail[field][subfield]. Many thanks

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `cocktail[field]`:

```
const drinkTypeHandler = (field, value) => {       
    const selectedType = cocktailList.filter((cocktail) => cocktail[field] === value);
    console.log(selectedType); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access object property using a variable, you need to use dot notation

```
const drinkTypeHandler = (field, value) => {       
    const selectedType = cocktailList.filter((cocktail) => cocktail[field] === value);
    console.log(selectedType); 
}
```

You can read more about [bracket and dot notation here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.1)